# How to find the total area of two overlapping equilateral triangles?

Tags: geometry

I am trying to write a program to find a total area of two overlapping equilateral triangles (in the picture, this area is all in grey). However, I can't find a good way to solve this problem because my Mathematics aptitude is just so-so.

Is there any equation that I can use to find to total area of two overlapping equilateral triangles? I also welcome algorithmic approach.

This is just some side project for me to improve on my understanding math problems. Not for homework because I am past University time.

Picture is here:

[Picture of Overlapping Equilateral triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0ydb.png)

Comment: Are there any other details provided ?

Comment: Hint: The overlapped area is also an equilateral triangle. The total area is then just the sum of the areas of the big equilateral triangles minus the area of the overlap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection of two equilateral triangles is an.... equilateral triangle!

Well, at least the type of intersection shown in your picture. Use the formula $\displaystyle A = \frac{s^2\sqrt{3}}{4}$ for each triangle.

Add up the two big triangle areas, and subtract the intersection triangle, to get the entire figure area.

Comment: This makes sense. Just to be sure, the s in the equation... is it referring to the side's length of each triangle?

Comment: Yup! [need to make this response 15 characters]

Comment: Remaining area is a trepisium which are same so the remaining area can obtained by using the formula (.5*(a+b)h)